# Aligning JavaScript image with HTML images

Tags: javascript, html, css

There are four images I wish to be in one line. Three images have been uploaded to my website while the fourth is generated from JavaScript. Three of the images are aligned but the JavaScript image falls underneath to the next line. How can I fix this?

```html
<h3 style="text-align: center;">
  <img alt="" class="pull-center" height="168" src="images/wedding-wire-badge.jpg" width="168">
  <img alt="" class="pull-center" height="168" src="images/WPIC-certification-logo11.png" width="151">
  <img alt="" class="pull-center" height="125" src="images/wpic-canada.png" width="250">
  <script src='//www.weddingwire.com/assets/vendor/widgets/ww-rated-2013-d545585beb7833eec3a4dc56cbb3224c.js' type='application/javascript'>
  </script>
</h3>
<div id='ww-widget-wwrated-2013'>
  <h3 style="text-align: center;">
    <a class="ww-top" href="https://www.weddingwire.com" target="_blank" title="Weddings, Wedding, Wedding Venues"></a>
    <a class="ww-bottom" href="https://www.weddingwire.com/reviews/the-wedding-planner-plus-ocho-rios-island-wide/ebeea94a4b2d94b0.html" target="_blank" title="The Wedding Planner Plus Reviews, Jamaica Wedding Planning">
    </a>
    <script>
      WeddingWire.ensureInit(function() {
        WeddingWire.createWWRated2013({
          "vendorId": "ebeea94a4b2d94b0"
        });
      });
    </script>
  </h3>
</div>
<div id="ww-widget-wwrated-2013"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope It works for you, Thanks :-)

```html
<h3 style="text-align: center; display:inline">
  <img alt="" class="pull-center" height="168" src="images/wedding-wire-badge.jpg" width="168">
  <img alt="" class="pull-center" height="168" src="images/WPIC-certification-logo11.png" width="151">
  <img alt="" class="pull-center" height="125" src="images/wpic-canada.png" width="250">
  <script src='//www.weddingwire.com/assets/vendor/widgets/ww-rated-2013-d545585beb7833eec3a4dc56cbb3224c.js' type='application/javascript'>
  </script>
</h3>
<div id='ww-widget-wwrated-2013' style="display:inline-block">
  <h3 style="text-align: center;">
    <a class="ww-top" href="https://www.weddingwire.com" target="_blank" title="Weddings, Wedding, Wedding Venues"></a>
    <a class="ww-bottom" href="https://www.weddingwire.com/reviews/the-wedding-planner-plus-ocho-rios-island-wide/ebeea94a4b2d94b0.html" target="_blank" title="The Wedding Planner Plus Reviews, Jamaica Wedding Planning">
    </a>
    <script>
      WeddingWire.ensureInit(function() {
        WeddingWire.createWWRated2013({
          "vendorId": "ebeea94a4b2d94b0"
        });
      });
    </script>
  </h3>
</div>
<div id="ww-widget-wwrated-2013"></div>
```